# Why can't I rename a data frame column inside a list?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, names

I would like to rename some columns from CPU_Usage to the process name before I merge the dataframes  in order to make it more legible.

```
names(byProcess[[1]])
# [1] "Time"      "CPU_Usage"
names(byProcess[1])
# [1] "CcmExec_3344"
names(byProcess[[1]][2]) <- names(byProcess[1])
names(byProcess[[1]][2])
# [1] "CPU_Usage"
names(byProcess[[1]][2]) <- 'test'
names(byProcess[[1]][2])
# [1] "CPU_Usage"
lapply(byProcess, names)
# $CcmExec_3344
# [1] "Time"      "CPU_Usage"
#
# ... (removed several entries to make it more readable)
#
# $wrapper_1604
# [1] "Time"      "CPU_Usage"
```

Answer (score 5):

`names(l[[1]][2])` returns the names of the object which is `l[[1]][2]`. In your case this will be a `data.frame` with one column (`CPU_Usage`) using `names<-` will replace the names on this new object (and not replace `l[[1]]`)

if you want to use `names<-` on `l[[1]]`, you will need to have this as the argument to `names<-`

so

```
names(byProcess[[1])[2] <- names(byProcess[1])
```

performs the action you want

Comment: That also explains why when I used:

`names(byProcess[[i]]) <- c("Time", names(byProcess[i]) )`

it worked. The placing of the parenthesis makes perfect sense.

Thanks, mnel!